# custom reports rsProcessingaborted error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I have deployed CRM and installed the reporting extensions component successfully on the SSRS server with rollup2 (server and router match this) - I have separate servers for CRM , SQL and SSRS. The out the box reports work ok but the custom reports present an error "rsProcessingAborted" which to me sounds like permissions. I have read a number of articles relating to pepople with the same issue and have tried all possible fixes but still no joy.
SSRS runs under a svc_sqlserver acccount and this account has permissions in the DB
the datasources have all been created successfully and the custom reports are using the MSCRM_FetchDataSource which is configured with type Dynamics CRM Fetch and credentials supplied by the user running the report. The connection string says CustomerServicesCE which is the correct OrgsanisationID (as found within developer resources) - i have tried clearing this connection string, adding the server url, all possible combinations with no joy.

Within SSRS i cannot view the report, it says "cannot access the CRM datasource" - i read somewhere you need to enter the GUIDs systemuserid and organisationid as username and pwd but still no joy.

I tried amending one report to use the samedatasource as the out the box reports that work but still no joy which is the MSCRM_DataSource...................am i missing something?

These reports have come from another supplier - i don't mind how they are displayed (Fetch or otherwise) i just need them working!
interestingly i do get them working on my Development environment (after getting the same error) and to my eyes the setup looks identical!

thanks for any help
richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was to create an spn as
setspn -a http/crmservername domain\accountCRMrunsunderrIIS